# add AWS API gateway mapping template from sam template or swagger 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I am creating a aws based app with sam template So, I have my custom lambda authorizer so I need to add mapping template to the methods and i cant find a template that can do that

Answer (score 0):

HI after a lot of research I got the solution sharing it here if anybody faces the same problem. 
SAM template is actually a kind of a cloudformation template so most cloudformation syntaxes will work on SAM template (may be not directly but with some effort you can do it)
Here is What i did

```
# All the Resources are defined Here
Resources:
  MyApiGatewayWrapper:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Description: Sam generated  API Endpoint for My web app
    Properties:
      Name: My Api Gateway Wrapper
      StageName: prod
      DefinitionBody:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: stages/care_now_24-prod-swagger-apigateway.yaml
```